# CONVERT function not work properly

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In my `localhost` I have Mysql 5.7 and in my server I have MariaDB 10.2.7 .

I have some `json` fields and I want sort my records by one of fields in `json` values, I search in google and stackoverflow and so I use this query :

```
SELECT id , CONVERT(JSON_EXTRACT(name, '$."fa-IR"') USING utf8) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci AS cName FROM `users` ORDER BY cName ASC
```

Sample Data:

```
id   |   Name    
-----+-------------------
1    | {"fa-IR":"\u062a\u0633\u062a","en-US":"Test"}
```

This function work without any problem in my localhost (MySQL) but not work in server (MariaDB) I mean my records cannot sort properly and show broken up !

Comment: "Not work" means what?

Comment: @tadman records cannot sort properly, for example if records should sort by A,B,C,D,... in MariaDB sort like this C,D,B,A (but not random and each time I run this query return a same result)

Comment: Have you explored how MySQL and MariaDB handle sorting those values independent of JSON being a factor?

Comment: @tadman Sorry but I cannot understand your mean, Does your mean I should not use CONVERT ?

Comment: I mean that in order to get to the bottom of this, try a simpler case first. Example: A table with a `VARCHAR(255)` column and some of your test data in it as just plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Do not feed Unicode to MySQL.  Especially not with the `\u`.

In your client use UTF-8 encoding, then configure MySQL to use `utf8` (or `utf8mb4`).

See "Best practice" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored